# Entropy sources used by modern Windows

Tags: windows, random, entropy

A [comment](https://web.archive.org/web/20180929235240/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/michael_howard/2005/01/14/cryptographically-secure-random-number-on-windows-without-using-cryptoapi/#comment-5543) on a Microsoft blog from 2005 mentions over 150 sources of entropy for the Windows `CryptGenRandom` function. The majority of sources come from low-level system information (precise stat counters), the process' environment block, high-precision CPU counters, exception information, process information, and more. I have two questions about this entropy collection:

1. Are all these entropy sources still used on modern Windows, more than a decade later?
2. Are these sources queried at each randomness request, or is an entropy pool used?

The only [two](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/%7Edolev/pubs/thesis/msc-thesis-leo.pdf) [sources](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/store/writing-secure-code-9780735617223) I could find give no information for modern Windows (post-XP).

Comment: iirc, they use fortuna, which means a pool. CryptGenRandom has largely been outmoded by .NET's RNGCryptoServiceProvider, which uses HWRNG.

Comment: Here's the [Win10 DRBG FIPS 140-2 cert](https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/Cryptographic-Algorithm-Validation-Program/details?source=DRBG&number=2037). That page doesn't contain any useful info, but I wonder if questions could be asked to get access to some of the implementation docs for that certification?

Comment: @forest, I updated the link to an archived version.

Comment: @nobody Thanks! That's strange. I tried to open it in the Web Archive but it only claimed to have crawled it once in 2021 and once in 2020. How'd you find one from 2018?

Comment: "At a high level, the TPM collects and stores measurements from multiple early boot components and boot configuration data to create a system identifier (much like a fingerprint) for that computer. It stores each part of this fingerprint as a hash in a 160-bit platform configuration register (PCR)" - from WIndows Internals, 6th ed.

Comment: "The current implementation of the Random class is based on a modified version of Donald E. Knuth's subtractive random number generator algorithm. For more information, see D. E. Knuth. The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 2: Seminumerical Algorithms. Addison-Wesley, Reading, MA, third edition, 1997." -https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=net-5.0

Comment: "With Microsoft CSPs, CryptGenRandom uses the same random number generator used by other security components. This allows numerous processes to contribute to a system-wide seed. CryptoAPI stores an intermediate random seed with every user."  - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptgenrandom

Comment: "To form the seed for the random number generator, a calling application supplies bits it might have—for instance, mouse or keyboard timing input—that are then combined with both the stored seed and various system data and user data such as the process ID and thread ID, the system clock, the system time, the system counter, memory status, free disk clusters, the hashed user environment block." - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptgenrandom

Comment: "This result is used to seed the pseudorandom number generator (PRNG). In Windows Vista with Service Pack 1 (SP1) and later, an implementation of the AES counter-mode based PRNG specified in NIST Special Publication 800-90 is used. In Windows Vista, Windows Storage Server 2003, and Windows XP, the PRNG specified in Federal Information Processing Standard (FIPS) 186-2 is used." - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptgenrandom

Comment: The last three quotes are continuous, but segmented here to fit as comments, while useful they are not a true answer.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Are all these entropy sources still used on modern Windows, more than
>    a decade later?
> 2. Are these sources queried at each randomness request, or is an entropy
>    pool used?

1. When you say Modern Windows, do you mean Windows 10 and up? CryptGenRandom has been deprecated in favor of Cryptography Next Generation API: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccng/cng-portal.
2. Similar question raised here, with the closest answer: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/39566/where-do-windows-applications-get-entropy-from

Comment: That only describes the API. I'm asking about the sources the kernel uses to collect entropy.